# Browsers Back button Issues with CSRF Prevention Mechanisam

Tags: java, security, web, struts-1, owasp

I tried using OWASAP mechanism to protect my legacy application form CSRF, but i got issues with navigation and back button. I then tried using struts-1 token mechanism but faced the same issue. The problem i think with token injection mechanism is initially we will generate a token in jsp and store it in session and perform some action.

Consider  A.jsp. lets take token value 1 in the jsp and we will store the same in the session.
Now we will validate it in the filter/Action class. 
After that we will do some other operation in B.jsp and we will have token new value 2 in the jsp and in session.After validation form server we will be having value 2 in session.
Now if we navigate using browsers back button and move to page 1 and submit it, it will load the values from cache and the A.jsp will have the value 1 as token,
After submitting A.jsp at this point it will show CSRF error as it contradicts the value in session.

Is there a way to implement the CSRF prevention mechanism without actually disturbing the application?

Comment: Hi Girish, You have mentioned that 'I was successful in using one token per session without any navigation problems'. Could you please explain how did you achieve this? I am having back button navigation issues with CSRF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand your problem correctly, pressing back button you get page from cache with old token?  If I'm correct, then there is an easy way how to solve this problem - do not cache your pages, and load them from server all the time.

It can be achieved by setting following response headers

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate
```

Other, more difficult way, is to implement single page application, in that case you'll always have actual token in browser memory.

Comment: I tried to implement using the response headers.That didn't help as it is breaking the flow. Implementing SPA to the legacy app needs ample amount of time,which i don't have now. Is there any other way to protect the web app from CSRF without actually compromising the functionality.

Comment: There is no other from security token way to protect your site from CSRF. You can try and issue token not for single use, but for some reasonable period of time if it helps.

Comment: How good is checking the referrer header or other method using custom header where we will be setting the custom header in Action class and after passing it to jsp,we will set the same value in response header with javascript and  compare the values in server for the same. How secure is this  Cookie-to-Header Token method?